# Simple CriteriaQuery in JPA Criteria API that is too much for a noob

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I am trying to write following SQL query using JPA Criteria API

```
SELECT * FROM roles WHERE roles.name IN (SELECT users.role FROM users where name="somename");
```

and it is a bit to much for me (I have just started learing Criteria API). I got something like this:

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RoleEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RoleEntity.class);
    Root<RoleEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(RoleEntity.class);

    Subquery<UserEntity> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(UserEntity.class);
    Root<UserEntity> subqueryRoot = subquery.from(UserEntity.class);
    subquery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(subqueryRoot.get(UserEntity_.username), username));
    subquery.select(subqueryRoot);
```

And I have no idea how to put it all together.

Best regards,
Bartek

Comment: Just an opinion: I love JPA, I've used Hibernate's `Criteria` before and yet I've stayed away from JPA `Criteria`. It's complexity brings no added value to me.

Comment: Well, I agree, it is way to complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fellow JPA learner here.  Here's my attempt at setting it up:

```
// Get the criteria builder from the entity manager
CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Create a new criteria instance for the main query, the generic type indicates overall query results
CriteriaQuery<RoleEntity> c = cb.createQuery(RoleEntity.class);
// Root is the first from entity in the main query
Root<RoleEntity> role = criteriaQuery.from(RoleEntity.class);

// Now setup the subquery (type here is RETURN type of subquery, should match the users.role)
Subquery<RoleEntity> sq = cb.subquery(RoleEntity.class);
// Subquery selects from users
Root<UserEntity> userSQ = sq.from(UserEntity.class);
// Subquery selects users.role path, NOT the root, which is users
sq.select(userSQ.get(UserEntity_.role))
  .where(cb.equal(userSQ.get(UserEntity_.username), username)); // test for name="somename"

// Now set the select list on the criteria, and add the in condition for the non-correlated subquery
c.select(role)
  .where(cb.in(role).value(sq));  // can compare entities directly, this compares primary key identities automatically
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: How is that you used `userSQ.select(userSQ.get(UserEntity_.role))
  .where(cb.equal(userSQ.get(UserEntity_.username), username));` according to this: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Root.html) there is no such method as select in Root interface.